# Macabre story about jazz -- not Charles Beaumont?

Tags: story-identification, horror, music

I'm searching for a horror story that I read as a teen in the late '60s. It's about a jazz musician who is jealous of another band's success and sets out to destroy them. IIRC, he ends up amputating the guitarist's fingers.

I originally thought it was by Charles Beaumont. At the time, I did have a copy of his collection *The Magic Man*, but in looking at online tables of contents, I don't see any titles that would fit this story. It's definitely not "The Black Country," although that's a fine story in its own right. I'm still searching as much of Beaumont's work as is available online, but I'm starting to doubt that this story is by him.

I'd appreciate any leads -- a title, an author, anything like that.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this may be "Die, Maestro, Die" by Theodore Sturgeon https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?61703. He is not jealous of *another* band's success, he actually want to destroy his own band, because he ..... well read the story!